# How do I open Vim's Taglist plugin to the right side of the window?

Tags: vim, taglist

I have NERDTree on the left side of my Vim's window (and the main files in the center). Every time I open Taglist (:TlistToggle), it is displayed in the left side together with NerdTree.
I made a custom remapping for Taglist:

```
nnoremap <F3> :TlistToggle<CR>
```

How can I make Taglist open to the right side instead of the left side?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put into your vimrc:

```
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window   = 1
```

Comment: Works as of `NVIM v0.4.3`